# Run DOM-based Javascript from command line

Tags: javascript, dom

I have some Javascript that is interacting with the DOM from a website.

```
document.location.href="https://www.example.com";
```

It works well from Chrome console, but I would like to run that code from the command line. How can I do it? NodeJS gives "document is not defined" error.

Comment: What would you like to happen when you run this code?

Comment: What would `document` be in Node? And what DOM would you have when running a script in a command line environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use command line to inject Javascript code in a browser's DOM you actually need...**a browser that runs Javascript code ad has a DOM**.

You can go with something like [Selenium](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/index.html) or rely on a bridged library like https://github.com/prasmussen/chrome-cli

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is called jsdom! https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom

Answer (score 1):

When you run the code from browser the DOM api is included, so your code excutes accordingly and finds the the location object with information about the current document your on.  When you try to run it from command line using node.js the DOM api is not included which is why it gives you "document is not defined" error. Node.js is for excuting server side js code.